# pd.to_datetime not converting datetime into int for df.rolling calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm attempting to create a rolling average over 10 minutes on an irregularly time stepped data set. I get the error shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asosreaderpandas.py", line 13, in <module>
    df.rolling('10min').mean()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8900, in rolling
    on=on, axis=axis, closed=closed)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py", line 2469, in rolling
    return Rolling(obj, **kwds)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.validate()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/window.py", line 1478, in validate
    raise ValueError("window must be an integer")
ValueError: window must be an integer
```

This is my code that I am using to create my rolling average, I would manually input my timestamps, as that has solved my issue in the past, except the .txt file is 98,000 lines long...

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('KART.txt', header = 0)
#indexing the date format from txt file
pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
#creating ten minute average
df.rolling('10min').mean()
print(df)
```

I don't understand the pandas module well, I have tried multiple ways of assigning my datetime differently to no avail am I going about this completely wrong?

**Dataset Sample**

```
0,1
2019-01-01 00:00:00,4
2019-01-01 00:05:00,4
2019-01-01 00:10:00,4
2019-01-01 00:15:00,4
2019-01-01 00:25:00,5
2019-01-01 00:30:00,4
2019-01-01 00:35:00,4
2019-01-01 00:40:00,4
2019-01-01 00:45:00,4
2019-01-01 00:50:00,4
2019-01-01 00:55:00,4
2019-01-01 00:56:00,4
2019-01-01 01:00:00,4
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues in you code:

1. you have an **automatic integer index** assigned to your dataframe when you load your dataframe without specifying the column index *(you later try to convert into datetime which is obviously not what you want)*
2. you don't save the index when you convert it to datetime

**Here's the fixed version:**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('KART.txt', header = 0, index_col=0)  # <- specified column index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')  # <- saving index when converting it to datetime
df.rolling('10min').mean()
>                     1
0   
2019-01-01 00:00:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:05:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:10:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:15:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:25:00 5.0
2019-01-01 00:30:00 4.5
2019-01-01 00:35:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:40:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:45:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:50:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:55:00 4.0
2019-01-01 00:56:00 4.0
2019-01-01 01:00:00 4.0
...
```

---

**EDIT**
Thanks to the comment of [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait) you can be get even a shorter version of a code by parsing dates right in the `read_csv` method:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('KART.txt', 
                 header = 0, 
                 index_col=0,  # <-- specified column index
                 parse_dates=True)  # <-- parsed dates from txt

df.rolling('10min').mean()
```

Comment: And [`read.csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has *parse_dates* argument where you can avoid second line.